# How to get selected path and name of the file opened with file dialog?

Tags: excel, vba

I need the path name and file name of the file that is opened with File Dialog. I want to show this information with a hyperlink in my worksheet.

With this code I have the file path:

```
Sub GetFilePath()

Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With myFile
    .Title = "Choose File"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
FileSelected = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = FileSelected
End Sub
```

I'm still looking for a way to get the filename.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim cl As Range

    Set cl = ActiveCell
    ' Open the file dialog
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Show
        ' Display paths of each file selected
        For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            ' Add Hyperlinks
            cl.Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=cl, Address:=.SelectedItems(lngCount), _
                TextToDisplay:=.SelectedItems(lngCount)
            ' Add file name
            'cl.Offset(0, 1) = _
            '    Mid(.SelectedItems(lngCount), InStrRev(.SelectedItems(lngCount), "\") + 1)
            ' Add file as formula
            cl.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
                 "=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-1],""\"",REPT("" "",99)),99))"


            Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
        Next lngCount
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hehe, I deleted my post because it was identical to yours. The OP can rest assured it will work :-)

Comment: Tx, this is exactly what i needed for the file path part! :D

Answer (score 14):

You can get any part of the file path using the FileSystemObject. GetFileName(filepath) gives you what you want.

Modified code below:

```
Sub GetFilePath()
Dim objFSO as New FileSystemObject

Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With myFile
.Title = "Choose File"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show <> -1 Then
Exit Sub
End If
FileSelected = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = FileSelected 'The file path
ActiveSheet.Range("A2") = objFSO.GetFileName(FileSelected) 'The file name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

To extract only the filename from the path, you can do the following:

```
varFileName = Mid(fDialog.SelectedItems(1), InStrRev(fDialog.SelectedItems(1), "\") + 1, Len(fDialog.SelectedItems(1)))
```

Comment: Simple, one line solution. Great! Just what I needed.

Comment: Yeah, same her @riderBill.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want this:

```
Dim filename As String
filename = Application.GetOpenFilename

Dim cell As Range
cell = Application.Range("A1")
cell.Value = filename
```

Comment: Tx for your reaction. I think i didn't make myself very clear. I need to open a file. Of that file i need to know the file path and the filename. I have found a solution to get the filepath. I add it in my question.

Comment: I don't get my filename, maybe because I use FileDialog?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simplest way to get to what you want.

Credit to JMK's answer for the first part, and the hyperlink part was adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490(v=office.15).aspx

```
'Gets the entire path to the file including the filename using the open file dialog
Dim filename As String
filename = Application.GetOpenFilename

'Adds a hyperlink to cell b5 in the currently active sheet
With ActiveSheet
 .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("b5"), _
 Address:=filename, _
 ScreenTip:="The screenTIP", _
 TextToDisplay:=filename
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

The below command is enough to get the path of the file from a dialog box -

```
my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.tsv), *.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

FileNameOnly = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))

Answer (score 0):

The code starts file search from root colon, If I want to start search from a specific directory, to avoid going to that directory every time, where I should put one. I did it like

```
Sub GetFilePath()
FileSelected = "G:\Audits\A2010"
Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With myFile
.Title = "Choose File"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show <> -1 Then
Exit Sub
End If
FileSelected = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

ActiveSheet.Range("C14") = FileSelected
End Sub
```

But it could not start reach from "G:\Audits\A2010"

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do:

```
Dim filename As String
filename = Application.GetOpenFilename
```

Answer (score 0):

From office 2010, we won't be able to use the common dialog box control, so it's nice to use the Application object to get the desired results.

Here I got a text box and Command button - paste the following code under the command button click event, which will open the file dialog box and add the File name to the Text box.

```
Dim sFileName  As String

sFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("MS Excel (*.xlsx), *.xls")

TextBox1.Text = sFileName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub GetFilePath()

Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

With myFile

.Title = "Choose File"

.AllowMultiSelect = False

If .Show <> -1 Then

Exit Sub

End If

FileSelected = Replace(.SelectedItems(1), .InitialFileName, "")

End With

ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = FileSelected

End Sub
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please explain to the questioner what was the main problem. And you could also format your code to look nicer (remove excess empty lines for example).

Answer (score -1):

After searching different websites looking for a solution as to how to separate the full path from the file name once the full one-piece information has been obtained from the Open File Dialog, and seeing how "complex" the solutions given were for an Excel newcomer like me, I wondered if there could be a simpler solution. So I started to work on it on my own and I came to this possibility.
(I have no idea if somebody got the same idea before. Being so simple, if somebody has, I excuse myself.)

> ```
> Dim fPath As String
> Dim fName As String
> Dim fdString As String
>
> fdString = (the OpenFileDialog.FileName)
>
> 'Get just the path by finding the last "\" in the string from the end of it
>  fPath = Left(fdString, InStrRev(fdString, "\"))
>
> 'Get just the file name by finding the last "\" in the string from the end of it
>  fName = Mid(fdString, InStrRev(fdString, "\") + 1)
>
> 'Just to check the result
>  Msgbox "File path: " & vbLF & fPath & vbLF & vblF & "File name: " & vbLF & fName
> ```

AND THAT'S IT!!!  Just give it a try, and let me know how it goes...

Comment: God help me! I've just realized Fabio Reche had already given the same solution (Oct 2, 15), although not as complete as mine, but the same, and right below mine! Might be due to its brevity, just one line and I didn't see it. My apologies to you, Fabio.

Comment: This solution doesn't compile in Excel (2016). It doesn't like this line: `fdString = (the OpenFileDialog.FileName)`  I'm not familiar with `the` as a keyword. Also, for OpenFileDialog, does there need to be a reference enabled?