# Copy data from files with variable name

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 files that I copy data from, They come each month and have the always the same start in the name but the end changes each month. I have tried and tried but get nowhere.

This works, But here I have changed the names just to make it work, I have also changed the name of the file just for this test.

```
    Windows("Försäljningsdata Aktuell period.xlsx").Activate
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Datamatchningsfil Master.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Försäljningsdata").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Below you see the date, this will change each month. have tried with * # but don't get the hang of it. Also August will be changed each month, this I can get changed so it comes as 201708 and i think that could ease things up.

```
Windows("Copy of CDPPT_KPI_2017.08-2017.08_43.xlsx").Activate
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Datamatchningsfil Augusti.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Försäljningsdata").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Can you provide a list of filenames (so we don't have only one file) how they really look like? So it is easier to see the pattern. And you should avoid using `.Select` or `.Activate` which is bad practice and slows down your code a lot. The whole task can be done without.

Comment: I use a lot of recording and also find codes on the internet that I use, I am not yet into hard coding :(  How do I do it without .Select and .Activate ?  So these are the files I have right now     CDPPT_KPI_2017.07-2017.07_c1   CDPPT_KPI_2017.09-2017.09_c2    Electra sales August      Electra sales July

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I get new files each month that have new endings. I want to copy the data into one workbook. This I want to do without rename them. Here next month will be with new numbers, Also in 2018 there will be a change, Copy of CDPPT_KPI_2017.08-2017.08_43.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a function for this task and removed all the unnecessary `.select`. To call that function you need to know the exact file name.

```
Public Sub DoActions()
    DoMyAction "Copy of CDPPT_KPI_2017.08-2017.08_43.xlsx", "Datamatchningsfil Augusti.xlsm"
End Sub


Public Function DoMyAction(SourceFile As String, DestinationFile As String)
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = Workbooks(SourceFile).Worksheets(1) 'source is the first worksheet in the file

    With wsSource
        .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy
    End With

    Workbooks(DestinationFile).Worksheets("Försäljningsdata").Range("A2").PasteSpecial _
       Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Function
```

To find the exact filename you can e.g. use a FileDialogBox to let the user select a file (see
[How to get selected path and name of the file using open file dialog control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687536/how-to-get-selected-path-and-name-of-the-file-using-open-file-dialog-control)).

Or if the file is already opened in Excel then you could use a loop looping through all workbooks to find a specific pattern.

```
Public Sub ExampleToFindAWorkbookByPattern()
    Dim iWb As Workbook, FoundWb As Workbook
    For Each iWb In Workbooks 'loop throug all workbooks
        ' look if there is "2017.08" in it's name
        If InStr(1, iWb.Name, "2017.08") <> 0 Then
            Set FoundWb = iWb 'name was found, set workbook in FoundWb
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next iWb

    'now you can use it e.g.
    DoMyAction FoundWb.Name, "Datamatchningsfil Augusti.xlsm"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but since the numbers of one file changes, and the name in the other due to different months I have hard time to understand how this can work.  The start of the file name is the same so maybee the second version but use "CDPPT_KPI_"  for one file and "Electra" for the other?

Comment: @Sture I'm sorry that I can't give you a full working solution. This site is to help people solving their issues on their own. So there are the 2 options to (1) find an already open workbook by a static pattern or (2) let the user select a file from file system with the open dialog control. I gave an example for both. I cannot decide for you what or how you implement something, that's your task now. If you don't have much skills in coding VBA yet then consider to (a) learn at least the basics first or (b) hire someone to do the task for you.

Comment: That I know, and I am very greatful for your help. I am trying with second option and got it to work with changing name, am now  trying to get it to work for the other files. Thank you so much!