# How to select and referencing path in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to select and referencing a path in a cell (to use it later to save some files).

I've tried the following code:

```
Sub SelectPath()
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim cl As Range

    Set cl = ActiveCell
    ' Open the file dialog
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Show
        ' Display paths of each file selected
        For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count

            ' Add Hyperlinks
            cl.Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=cl, Address:=.SelectedItems(lngCount), _
                TextToDisplay:=.SelectedItems(lngCount)

            Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
        Next lngCount
    End With
End Sub
```

With this I'm able to select a file and put the path with the filename in the cell (in hyperlink format).

What I want is to be able to select only a path (not a file) and put it in a cell without the hyperlink (this second part is not really important).

How can I edit the code to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get selected path and name of the file using open file dialog control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687536/how-to-get-selected-path-and-name-of-the-file-using-open-file-dialog-control)

Comment: @TimStack, I doubt it's a duplicate since OP is interested in `msoFileDialogFolderPicker` more so than picking a file. However it is a straightforward copy of the code given as answer in your link. Hindsight OP should have researched more himself.

Answer (score 0):

ok, thank you for the answer!

I edited my code like this and now it does what I need to.

This is just the first part of a bigger workflow that I need to create.

Let me know if you have any comments on the code I wrote!

```
Sub SelezionaCartella()

    Set cl = ActiveCell

    ' Open the file dialog

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show

        ' Display path of folder selected
        For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count

            ' Add Hyperlink and add \ after folder path
            cl.Worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=cl, Address:=.SelectedItems(lngCount), _
                TextToDisplay:=.SelectedItems(lngCount) & "\"

        Next lngCount

    End With

End Sub
```