# How to integrate the name of the file into a working word counter macro

Tags: ms-word, counter, filenames, filedialog

I managed to adapt a vba macro (which I also found here) and got it running. So when the macro is started a file dialog asks me for the source file and the output gives me the word count of this file into cell "A1".

```
Public Sub word_counter()
    
    Dim objWord As Object, objDocument As Object
    Dim strText As String
    Dim lngIndex As Long
    Dim cellrange As String
    Dim intChoice As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = False
    
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
    strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
        msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
    Set objDocument = objWord.documents.Open(strPath)
    strText = objDocument.Content.Text
    objDocument.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    For lngIndex = 0 To 31
        strText = Replace(strText, Chr$(lngIndex), Space$(1))
    Next
    
    Do While CBool(InStr(1, strText, Space$(2)))
        strText = Replace(strText, Space$(2), Space$(1))
    Loop
    
    Sheets("calc tool").Select
    Range("A1") = UBound(Split(strText, Space$(1)))
    
    
    objWord.Quit
    
    Set objDocument = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Now i want to add the filename to the output as text in cell "A2" right next to the word count of this file.

A1: 1234 A2: filename.docx

I tried to add the solution described in the SOF question 12687536
[here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687536/how-to-get-selected-path-and-name-of-the-file-opened-with-file-dialog)

The results were disappointing and i ran into compiling errors or run time error '91'

This was one of my solutions which didn't work out.

```
Public Sub word_count()
    
    Dim objWord As Object, objDocument As Object
    Dim strText As String
    Dim lngIndex As Long
    Dim cellrange As String
    Dim intChoice As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim cell As Range
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = False
    
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
    intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
    strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
        msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
    Set objDocument = objWord.documents.Open(strPath)
    strText = objDocument.Content.Text
    objDocument.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    For lngIndex = 0 To 31
        strText = Replace(strText, Chr$(lngIndex), Space$(1))
    Next
    
    Do While CBool(InStr(1, strText, Space$(2)))
        strText = Replace(strText, Space$(2), Space$(1))
    Loop
    
    Sheets("calc tool").Select
    Range("A1") = UBound(Split(strText, Space$(1)))
    
    filename = Application.GetOpenFilename
    cell = Application.Range("A2")
    cell.Value = filename
    
    objWord.Quit
    
    Set objDocument = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: That's an abysmal approach to getting the word count. All you need is: objDocument.ComputeStatistics (wdStatisticWords) or objDocument.ComputeStatistics (0)

Answer (score 0):

You have to select a sheet before you can use `Range()`.

Thus change

```
cell = Application.Range("A2")
cell.Value = filename
```

to

```
Range("A2") = filename
```

or better

```
Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = filename
```

and you write the filename into the cell A2 in your active sheet.

Comment: This is a step forward! The macro is passing without any error and i get both results (word count and filename with path)

Unfortunately the output is the full path instead of the filename "excel sheet.xlsx".
Furthermore i get two dialog boxes for selecting the file.
1. Application.FileDialog & 2. Application.GetOpenFilename

Any idea how to simplify this with 1 dialog box?